# Updating Google Tag Manager container via API using R: invalidArgument error

Tags: r, google-api, google-tag-manager, httr

I am trying to write an R script to programmatically update a Google Tag Manager container via API and I have hit a bit of a wall getting it to work, as it keeps returning an invalid argument error. The problem is that I can't quite figure out what the problem is.

The documentation for the API call is here:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/update

Here's the code:

```
library(httr)

url_base <- 'https://www.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v2'
url_path <- paste('accounts',account_id,'containers',container_id,sep='/')

api_url <- paste(url_base,url_path,sep='/')

#since the instructions indicate that the request body parameters are all optional, let's just send a new name

call <- PUT(api_url,
        add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", gtm_token$credentials$access_token)),
        encode = 'json',
        body = list(name = 'new name'))

call_content <- content(call,'parsed')
```

This is a pretty standard API call to the GTM API, and in fact I have written a bunch of functions for other GTM API methods that work in the same way, so I am a bit perplexed as to why this one keeps failing:

```
$error
$error$errors
$error$errors[[1]]
$error$errors[[1]]$domain
[1] "global"

$error$errors[[1]]$reason
[1] "invalidArgument"

$error$errors[[1]]$message
[1] "Bad Request"

$error$code
[1] 400

$error$message
[1] "Bad Request"
```

It seems like the issue is in the message body, but it's not clear if the issue is down to the API expecting different information / more parameters, when the documentation suggests that all of the parameters are optional.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the documentation is lacking here. This works if you include a name at least. Here's a working function:

```
gtm_containers_update <- function(account_id,container_id,container_name,usage_context,domain_name,notes,token) {

  require(httr)

  token$refresh()

  #create the post url
  api_url <- paste('https://www.googleapis.com/tagmanager/v2','accounts',account_id,'containers',container_id,sep='/')

  #create the list with required components

  call_body <- list(name = container_name,
                    usageContext = list(usage_context),
                    notes = notes,
                    domainName = domain_name)

  call <- POST(url,
              add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", token$credentials$access_token)),
              encode = 'json',
              body = call_body)

  print(paste('Status code:',call$status_code))

}
```